# Inversion of asymptotic series

Tags: probability, statistics, asymptotics

I have the following equation which involves a power series expansion
$$
\alpha_1+A_1=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty (\alpha_{k+1}+A_{k+1})x^k/k!,
$$
where $\alpha_j=O(1)$ and $A_j=O_p(n^{-1/2})$, $j\in\{1,2,\ldots\}$ and $n\rightarrow\infty$. I'd like to find the inverse series of $x$ as a function of $\alpha_1+A_1$. In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem) it is pointed the solution to this problem. However, I have second thoughts about the validity of this result in my case because I know that when $\alpha_1=0$ then $x=O_p(n^{-1/2})$, otherwise $x=O(1)$. It is clear that in the first case the right hand-side of the equation converges to $0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, whereas in the second case it diverges. Bottom line is: does the solution pointed in Wikipedia hold when the power series is not convergent? If not, could you please tell me if it possible at all to find a valid series expansion for $x$ and, in case the answer is positive, how to?

Comment: I worked out the formula given in Wikipedia to see if there are some conditions to ensure the convergence of the inverse series which is of the form $\sum_{k=0}^\infty g_k (\alpha_1+A_1)^k/k!$. After some algebra I found out that $g_k=O(1)$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, which is of course trivial. Since $(\alpha_1+A_1)^k=\alpha_1^k+O_p(n^{-1/2})$ the series should converge as $n$ diverges provided $|\alpha_1|<1$. The nice thing is that the truncation error is $O(\alpha_1^k)$ + $O_p(n^{-1/2})$, so for sufficiently large $n$ it is $O(\alpha_1^k)$. Does this make sense?

Comment: Currently the question is confusing and unclear, could you please add the function $f(x)$ that you would like to invert or the actual problem you like to solve? The equation you provide is of the form $\sum_k c_k x^k/k!=0$ with $c_k=\alpha_{k+1}+A_{k+1}$, which implies $c_k=0$. The inversion works at least locally, provided the function is analytic at the point of interest and hence the series is required to converge locally as well. However, it does not have to be convergent on the whole of the available domain.

Comment: I have some analytic function $h(x)$ and of this function I know that $h(\tilde x)=0$. The point $\tilde x$ depends on $n$ and actually I need to study the behavior of $\tilde x-x_0$ as $n$ diverges, with $x_0$ some fixed point. To this end I develop the series expansion $h(\tilde x)=h(x_0)+(\tilde x-x_0)h^{'}(x_0)+\ldots=0\rightarrow h(x_0)=-(\tilde x-x_0)h^{'}(x_0)-\ldots$. To match the notation above, $h(x_0)\equiv\alpha_1+A_1$, $h^{'}(x_0)\equiv\alpha_2+A_2$, and so forth, while $x \equiv\tilde x - x_0$.

Comment: Usually I invert the series when $\alpha_1=0$, but with the usual method I am used I got stucked. I must say that the series I get from Wikipedia result with $\alpha_1=0$ matched the one I am used to derive. I work in the field of statistics and usually we worry little about the convergence of the series (let's say that we are just happy to know that the error goes to zero at some specified rate which depends on $n$), however I am concerned about the legitimacy of using Lagrange's theorem when $\alpha\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is going to be a bit messy. The way in which $x$ depends on $n$ is for the first part not important.

Given a function $h(x)$ and a point $x_0$ we can make a Taylor expansion in $\delta \equiv x-x_0$
$$
h(x)=h(x_0) + \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{h^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!} \delta^k
$$
If we define $y \equiv h(x)$ and in particular $y_0 = h(x_0)$, we can also write the inverse function $x = h^{-1}(y) \equiv g(y)$ with $g(y_0)=x_0$ and like-wise make a Taylor expansion about $y_0$ in $\epsilon \equiv y-y_0$.
$$
g(y)=g(y_0) + \sum_{l \geq 1} \frac{g^{(l)}(y_0)}{l!} \epsilon^l.
$$
Since $h(x)-h(x_0)=y-y_0=\epsilon$ and $g(y)-g(y_0)=x-x_0=\delta$, we find
$$
\epsilon =  \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{h^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!} \delta^k
$$
$$
\delta =  \sum_{l \geq 1} \frac{g^{(l)}(y_0)}{l!} \epsilon^l
$$
and we can substitute the second in the first to obtain
$$
\epsilon = \sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{h^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!} \left( \sum_{l \geq 1} \frac{g^{(l)}(y_0)}{l!} \epsilon^l \right)^k
$$
Expanding this result we find that each group of terms of the same order in $\epsilon$ results in an equation that enable us to relate the derivatives $h^{(k)}(x_0)$ and $g^{(l)}(y_0)$: (I drop the arguments for convenience)
$$
{\cal O}(\epsilon) : h^{(1)} g^{(1)} - 1 = 0
$$
$$
{\cal O}(\epsilon^2) : h^{(1)} g^{(2)} + h^{(2)} \left(g^{(1)}\right)^2 = 0
$$
$$
{\cal O}(\epsilon^3) : h^{(1)} g^{(3)} + 3 h^{(2)} g^{(1)} g^{(2)} + h^{(3)} \left(g^{(1)}\right)^3 = 0
$$
which can uniquely be solved giving:
$$
g^{(1)} = \frac{1}{h^{(1)}}
$$
$$
g^{(2)} = -\frac{h^{(2)}}{\left( h^{(1)} \right)^3}
$$
$$
g^{(3)} = \frac{3 \left( h^{(2)} \right)^2 - h^{(1)} h^{(3)}}{\left( h^{(1)} \right)^5}
$$
The solutions are analytic, but a program like Mathematica is advisable for higher order terms. Note that the solution requires $h^{(1)}(x_0) \neq 0$. I also implicitly assumed that we restrict $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ to be in the domains where the Taylor series converge.

In order for this approach to be able to solve $h(\bar{x})=0$, it is required that $\bar{x}$ lies within the convergence domain of the expansion about $x_0$. We then have 
$$
\bar{x}=g(0)=g(y_0) + \sum_{l \geq 1} \frac{g^{(l)}(y_0)}{l!} (-y_0)^l
$$
and hence also $-y_0$ should be in the convergence domain of the expansion of $g(y)$ about $y_0$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the developments in your reply. Your approach is more or less the one I am used to: from a (stochastic) Taylor series I iteratively solve for the unknowns by equating to 0 terms of the same asymptotic order (in $n$). The crux here is that as long as $\alpha_1\neq 0$ I know for sure that, as $n$ diverges, $\tilde x-x_0=\xi\neq o_p(1)$, though this condition is only a necessary one for the series to converge.

Comment: If I truncate the series at some $k^{*}$, then the remainder of the Taylor series in the first post is $(\alpha_{k^{*}+1}+A_{k^{*}+1})(\tilde x-x_0)^{k^{*}+1}/(k^{*}+1)!$, which equals $\alpha_{k^{*}+1}O_p((\tilde x-x_0)^{k^{*}+1})/(k^{*}+1)!$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, so I can guess that the approximation is going to be poor, no matter how large is $k^{*}$. I must live with this and my point is: can I still invert this series?

Comment: Yes you can invert the series, but it is not clear whether this result will be very useful. There might be some other approaches, that will work better for your particular problem, but for the given generic problem that is hard to tell. I would recommend that you post a separate question with an actual example of the function and problem, which might result in a more appropriate suggestion for the solution.